# Installing PIP Package connectorx on Docker?

Tags: python, docker, docker-build

I'm developing a Lambda using Docker. I had this in requirements.txt:

> connectorx

I ran `docker-compose build` and got:

> Exception: connectorx is not installed. Please run `pip install connectorx>=0.3.1`.

I updated the line in requirements.txt to:

> connectorx>=0.3.1

Ran `docker-compose build` again and got:

> No matching distribution found for connectorx>=0.3.1

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you please post your docker-compose or Dockerfile , then only we can understand base-image or how you are trying to build.

Comment: seems related to this issue : https://github.com/sfu-db/connector-x/issues/240

The guys there suggest to build from source which I tried but I didn't succeed... It seems a year that the issue is there, dont know if there will be a whl file for Linux so soon

For my personal project it makes me switch to the good old pandas...

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this? I am experiencing the same but now with 0.3.2. Only alpha version are available. I am using public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9 as the base image and I am succesful in installing connectorx 0.3.2 with the same pip and python version on a local conda env